# How to apply OR rules in find of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```
db.media.find( {Released : {$gte: 1990, $lt : 2010}})
```

Looks for movies released between 1990<= to <2010 and this is an AND condition.

How to apply an OR condition in the query statement?

For example,

Looks for movies released before 2000 or type is of action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $or command in your queries.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or

Your query would look something like this:

```
db.media.find( { $or : [ { Released : { $lt: 2000 } }, { Type : "Action" } ]
```